# Compiling PHP from source fails on Mac Mini lion server

Tags: php, c, macos, unix

This is the message I get after I run `make` after I configure.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_res_9_init", referenced from:
      _zif_dns_check_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
  "_res_9_search", referenced from:
      _zif_dns_check_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
  "_res_9_dn_skipname", referenced from:
      _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
  "_res_9_dn_expand", referenced from:
      _php_parserr in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

How I'm configuring

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/ --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql \
--with-pear --with-pdo-pgsql \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock \
--with-pgsql --with-zlib \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-openssl \
--without-iconv \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--enable-sockets
```

Please can any one help?

Comment: What version on PHP are you trying to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual source of the problem remains vague but what is certain is that my configuration is wrong. The conflicts creating the problem were only resolved once all traces of the native php was removed -deleted literally from /usr/bin and then I downloaded the latest stable php 5.4 tarball unpacked it and reconfigured with these options:

```
./configure  \
--prefix=/usr  \
--mandir=/usr/share/man  \
--infodir=/usr/share/info  \
--sysconfdir=/private/etc  \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs  \
--enable-cli  \
--with-config-file-path=/etc  \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr  \
--with-openssl=/usr  \
--with-kerberos=/usr  \
--with-zlib=/usr  \
--enable-bcmath  \
--with-bz2=/usr  \
--enable-calendar  \
--with-curl=/usr  \
--enable-dba  \
--enable-exif  \
--enable-ftp  \
--with-gd  \
--enable-gd-native-ttf  \
--with-icu-dir=/usr  \
--with-iodbc=/usr  \
--with-ldap=/usr  \
--with-ldap-sasl=/usr  \
--with-libedit=/usr  \
--enable-mbstring  \
--enable-mbregex  \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd   \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd  \
--without-pear  \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd  \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock  \
--with-readline=/usr  \
--enable-shmop  \
--with-snmp=/usr  \
--enable-soap  \
--enable-sockets  \
--enable-sysvmsg  \
--enable-sysvsem  \
--enable-sysvshm  \
--with-tidy  \
--enable-wddx  \
--with-xmlrpc  \
--with-iconv-dir=/usr  \
--with-xsl=/usr  \
--enable-zip  \
--with-pcre-regex  \
--with-pgsql=/usr  \
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11 \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr  \
--with-png-dir=/usr/X11
```

after that I ran 
    $ sudo make test, then install.

then I restarted apache
    $ sudo serveradmin stop/start web

then It f******* worked.

Answer (score 1):

This more than 3 year old bug (mentioned [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49332), and [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49267), why haven't they fixed it yet?) can also be resolved by doing the following (or possibly by moving incorrect libraries out of the path, which may work as well).

Edit your `Makefile` and add the following flag to the `EXTRA_LIBS =` section (in addition to the other flags already there):

```
EXTRA_LIBS = -lsResolv
```

The second error you mentioned: `ext/phar/phar.php] Error 133` is caused by the fact that one of the files in the "lib" directory installed by the MySQL binary installer ***does not have an absolute path*** (this has been a bug for some time now, why doesn't Oracle fix it??).  If you look a few lines above the error line you mentioned, you'll see it say:

```
Generating phar.php
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/...
```

Check that file by doing this (replace the version number below with yours e.g mysql-5.x.xx). Note the result, that it does not include the full path like the other file references:

```
# otool -L /usr/local/mysql-5.6.14-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Then just fix it like so:

```
# sudo install_name_tool -id /usr/local/mysql-5.6.14-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.6.14-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Check it a second time to make sure:

```
# otool -L /usr/local/mysql-5.6.14-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Now, you should be able to compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Compile PHP using the native mysql and mysqli drivers. This error is caused by conflicts between php and mysql libs. If you don't want to use the native driver, then use "export EXTRA_CFLAGS=-lresolv", run a make and that will solve the undefined symbols.

Change your configure to:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/usr/ \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs 
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-pear --with-pdo-pgsql \
--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock \
--with-pgsql --with-zlib \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-openssl \
--without-iconv \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--enable-sockets
```

By the way, if you leave the mysql socket in /tmp, don't forget to do a "chmod +t /tmp"

Comment: okay, doesn't work. doesn't configure past apxs 
gives  /Users/Asgard/php-5.4.4/ext/phar/build_precommand.php > ext/phar/phar.php
make: *** [ext/phar/phar.php] Error 133
 message